# How to reshape data for LSTM - Time series multi class classification

Tags: time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I'm working on a time series classification using ASHRAE RP-1043 chiller multiple sensor data set which has 65 columns and more than 3000 rows for each chiller fault and normal condition. And I have used LSTM and I'm not quit sure the data structure I have used here is suitable for time series classification. Below is a image of my data frame created from the collected data set which contains records of multiple chiller conditions (both 7 faulty and normal). Each record has been labeled with relevant class(condition). And structured the data set from different files served faulty conditions and normal condition.
[image]

And the train data shape is as following
`X_train.shape,y_train.shape`

> ((81600, 65), (81600, 8))

But for LSTM input needs to be 3D. So reshaped into as following. (with only 1 time step)
# make it 3d  input
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1,1,65)
X_train.shape,y_train.shape`

> ((81600, 1, 65), (81600, 8))

```
def create_nn_model():
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],
  X_train.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
  model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(8,activation='softmax'))
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model
```

And this works for my model and i can fit without any error.

But how can i increase the number of time steps of X_train as in (100 time steps)

`scaled_x_train.reshape(-1,100,65) X_train.shape,y_train.shape`

> ((816, 100, 65), (81600, 8))

Now the X_train has been reshaped. But I cannot fit this due to the size difference of the X_train and y_train. I have tried reshaping the y_train the same way done to X_train but then i will have to return sequence which is not my requirement. Is there anything wrong with my data set structure(102000 rows and 65 columns)? Can i split my data shown in above image directly for training and testing or do i need to do more manipulating. Appreciate any help

P.S Related To Priya's answer
[image]

Comment: You can take the last time step even after returning the sequence, like if you have

Comment: @Priya Thanks for your response. But is my data frame structured in a proper way? I'm a bit doubt full on that

Comment: I think your DataFrame is fine and has all the chillers divided into two categories faulty and normal respectively, but while reading into the model, you need to subclass a Dataset class and use __getitem__(index) and take only one specific chiller's data samples at a time. This would be easy if you use pytorch or MXNet.

Comment: This data set belongs only to a one chiller with seven fault types and normal condition. And there are 8 class labels. and this should be a multi class classification as i feel

Comment: I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly reshape into this:

```
scaled_x_train.reshape(-1,100,65) X_train.shape,y_train.shape
```

This will not give error when the timesteps=1 because the `num_samples` in `x_train.shape = (num_samples,time_steps,num_features)` would not change. Since dim=1 can be created on any axis.

But when `time_steps>1`, `num_samples=len(dataset)-time_steps.`

I am including a snippet of code that creates input data for Lstm model assuming that last column is your target variable. I think rest of your model code is fine.

```
import numpy as np 

# FUNCTION TO CREATE 1D DATA INTO TIME SERIES DATASET
def new_dataset(dataset, time_steps):
    data_X, data_Y = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-time_steps):
        a = dataset[i:(i+time_steps), :-1]
        data_X.append(a)
        data_Y.append(dataset[i + time_steps, -1])
    return np.array(data_X), np.array(data_Y)
```

Comment: Got a error saying step_size is not defined

Comment: sorry for the typo, step_size=time_steps

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Even though we will lose last time step records from the data due to the subtraction of the time steps from data set length this enables us to group the data set into batch that contains defined amount of time steps and the class label for that batch. Thanks a lot to you ;)

Comment: Actually, we don't lose any records from the data because the line `data=dataset[i:i+time_steps]` would cover the whole range of data. Let's say we have 100 records of data, time_steps=10, then the "i" value ranges from (0-89), so (i+time_steps)=89+10=99...that means our last record...anyway glad it helped you!

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the code anyway. Data has been duplicated when appending to the X. Please check

Comment: Are there duplicates present in the data?.. I don't understand till I see the data....can you send the data link?

Comment: There is no duplicate data but as per the code the same time step is appended again and again will post a screen shot here anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can take the last time step even after returning the sequence, like if you have

```
num_categories=10
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_categories)
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
ypred = model.predict(x_test)

# Final layer shape after predict would be
# ypred.shape = (Num_samples, 100, 10)
# taking last time step
ypred = ypred[:,-1,:]  # will be of shape (Num_samples, 10)

# Prediction classes
ypred_classes = np.argmax(ypred,axis = -1)
```

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more like where are we setting the soft max loss function

Comment: if you have more than two classes to classify then set the softmax activation like tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax") or you can set loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy(from_logits=True) in model.compile() method.

Comment: I have updated my question with the model with LSTM layers code. can you please have alook

Comment: I have reshaped both my X and Y to have 10 time steps so the the batch numbers will not be different and it gives me all the time steps results when predicted in an array as in [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]  if we have 10 time steps shaped output. so i can take the last time step hidden state value as the predicted value for the passed time series sequence  right?

Comment: yes, that's right. Sorry for the typo in the code, step_size=time_steps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out on the basic working principle of RNNs or LSTMs. It's not data duplication...it is the way how RNNs work.

I will take a simple example here, let's say we have data consisting of three features and one target.

```
Temperature humidity pressure   target(binary, whether it will rain or not)
    
    63        89       29.8       1
    88        21.2     40.5       0
    72        90.3     48.7       1
    45        23.2     67.2       0
    90        10.8     32.6       0
```

Then let suppose we want our model to look back `3 timesteps` to learn the pattern in our data. So the way we structure our input data is by grouping 3 timesteps together.

```
# 0,1,2 index
[63, 89, 29.8,       Target data:
 88, 21.2, 40.5,     # datapoint at 3rd index in target
 72, 90.3, 48.7]     [0]

# 1,2,3 index
[88, 21.2, 40.5,     # datapoint at 4th index in target
 72, 90.3, 48.7       [0]
 45, 23.2, 67.2]

 # 2,3,4 index       # model should predict datapoint at 5th index in target
[72, 90.3, 48.7
 45, 23.2, 67.2       
 90, 10.8, 37.6]
```

So now input-data `shape=(3,3,3)`
Please read the docs on RNN before you implement otherwise it is pretty confusing.

Comment: Hi , I checked on many tutorials but couldn't find any learning material that related to that duplicating time step values like you have mentioned here. Could you please mention any if possible. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure. There is an amazing blog here https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check. But another problem i have is i have reshaped my current data frame ( as in first image posted here) doesn't have the values repeated in time steps within a one batch? ( i have reshaped both X_train and Y_train). Is there anything wrong with that? cCurrenlty im getting the last value of the 2D array im getting as the output.

Comment: No, it is not wrong and well, that means your time_steps=1. If time_steps=1, the network will only look back one time_step into the past and predict the next value. You can play around using different values of time_steps and check how the model is working.

Comment: But i reshaped(calling pandas reshape function) my X_train to the shape of (816, 100, 65) which means 816 batches and each batch contains 100 time steps (100 records as in my data set) and 65 columns. doesn't this mean that my model is not trained to look back 100 time steps ?

Comment: If you are using timesteps >1 then the input data has to have a repeated set of samples as I explained before ([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]...). I really don't understand what you mean by not having repeated values in time steps...

Comment: I meant that when I reshaped my data frame which is the size of (81600,65) using pandas reshape function it doesn't give me repeated values between the time steps like in your `([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]...)`. I think naturally reshaping doesn't give me repeated values between time steps. but it makes the shape into 3D with multiple time steps.

Comment: If it is possible can you move this into a discussion?

Comment: yeah we could move to chatroom

Comment: where is the chatroom link

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235147/room-for-sinfer-and-priya