# Reshape the tabular time series data for LSTM binary classification model

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I wanted to prepare data for LSTM binary classification model. I wanted to reshape my data into (num_samples,time_steps,num_features) shape. My training data set has the shape (2487576, 21). Here is my code for the toy data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/7381979ecafb7efd456421c324d7963a/raw/a50a653119471cd4fe323d7680fe82a161727169/test.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(url,sep="\t")
def generate_train_data(X, y, sequence_length=2, step = 1):
    X_local = []
    y_local = []
    for start in range(0, len(df) - sequence_length, step):
        end = start + sequence_length
        X_local.append(X[start:end])
        y_local.append(y[end-1])
    return np.array(X_local), np.array(y_local)

train_X_sequence, train_y = generate_train_data(df.loc[:, "V1":"V2"].values, df.Class)
```

Output:

```
train_X_sequence

       array([
        [[ 30, 100],
        [ 40, 200]],

       [[ 40, 200],
        [ 50, 300]],

       [[ 50, 300],
        [ 60, 400]],

       [[ 60, 400],
        [ 70, 500]],

       [[ 70, 500],
        [ 80, 600]],

       [[ 80, 600],
        [ 90, 700]]])
```

```
train_y

array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

I see that the last row is not showing up in the reshaped data. Is there anything I am missing here? I am using LSTM from tensorflow framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use the condition `len(df) - sequence_length + 1` in the `for` loop.

```py
for start in range(0, len(df) - sequence_length + 1, step):
```

Simple steps to prove it:

1. You want `y[end-1]` can access the last row of `df['Class']` whose index is `len(df)-1`, so `max(end)` should be `len(df)`
2. `end` is equal to `start + sequence_length`, so that means `max(start)` should be `len(df) - sequence_length`
3. As a result, `start` in the `for` loop should be `[0, len(df) - sequence_length + 1)`, where open bracket means value is included, close bracket means value is excluded.

Comment: Is train_y make sense?

Comment: @ForestGump What do you mean?

Comment: Is array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]) correct y corresponding to X?

Comment: @ForestGump Forgot to comment, if the y is calculated with your designed algorithm, it is corrected. However, if you want to say whether the algorithm is reasonable, my opinion is that it might not. The unreasonable part is that you treat label [0,1] as 1 and [1,0] as 0, while they are both two different label.

Comment: How abt this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371579/how-to-reshape-data-for-lstm-time-series-multi-class-classification?rq=1

Comment: I posted another question related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75932856/1d-cnn-input-data-shape-for-binary-classification-of-tabular-data/75953621#75953621