# 1D CNN input data shape for binary classification of tabular data

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have 2487576 observations and 21 variables. These observations are the daily records of 37000 hard drives sensors. I took 180 days of healthy drives and 360 days of failed drives's daily records. I am trying to create binary classification model using 1D CNN.

Toy data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JishanAhmed2019/7381979ecafb7efd456421c324d7963a/raw/a50a653119471cd4fe323d7680fe82a161727169/test.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(url,sep="\t")
```

For `TF.keras LSTM` model,  I have used the following data shape to create  `A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature]`

```
import numpy as np
def generate_train_data(X, y, sequence_length=5, step = 1):
    X_local = []
    y_local = []
    for start in range(0, len(df) - sequence_length+1, step):
        end = start + sequence_length
        X_local.append(X[start:end])
        y_local.append(y[end-1])
    return np.array(X_local), np.array(y_local)

train_X_sequence, train_y = generate_train_data(df.loc[:, "V1":"V2"].values, df.Class)
```

[image]

Then I have used `input_shape = (5, 21))` in my LSTM model since I have 21 variables and 5 time steps.

For `1D CNN`, I wanted to create `3+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`. I am confused with the following data shape for the 1D CNN. Why do we have to use input_dim=1? How is it different than LSTM data shape?

```
X=df.drop('Class',axis=1)
y=df['Class']
X=X.values
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1)
```

[image]

```
 batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)
```

Toy example:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Conv1D, Dense, Flatten

# Toy dataset
data = np.array([
    [1, 0.1, 0.5, 0],
    [2, 0.3, 0.7, 0],
    [3, 0.2, 0.9, 1],
    [4, 0.4, 0.6, 1],
    [5, 0.1, 0.4, 0],
    [6, 0.8, 0.2, 0]
])

# Features and labels
X = data[:, 1:3]
y = data[:, 3]

# LSTM input data
def generate_train_data(X, y, sequence_length=3, step = 1):
    X_local = []
    y_local = []
    for start in range(0, len(data) - sequence_length+1, step):
        end = start + sequence_length
        X_local.append(X[start:end])
        y_local.append(y[end-1])
    return np.array(X_local), np.array(y_local)
X_lstm, y_lstm = generate_train_data(X, y)

# 1D CNN input data
X_cnn = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1)
y_cnn = y

# LSTM model
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape=(sequence_length, 2)))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
lstm_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# 1D CNN model
cnn_model = Sequential()
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(16, 2, activation='relu', input_shape=(2, 1)))
cnn_model.add(Flatten())
cnn_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
cnn_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the LSTM model
lstm_model.fit(X_lstm, y_lstm, epochs=10)

# Train the 1D CNN model
cnn_model.fit(X_cnn, y_cnn, epochs=10)
```

Is my Toy example correctly present the data preparation steps for CNN and LSTM for binary classification?

Answer (score 0):

In LSTM, the data shape is [batch, timesteps, feature], where timesteps represent the number of steps in the sequence and feature represents the number of input features at each time step.

The 1D CNN expects input data to be in the shape of [batch, steps, input_dim], where steps represent the number of data points in the 1D spatial dimension, and input_dim represents the number of channels or input features at each data point.

In your example, you have 21 variables and you want to use a 1D CNN. You reshape the input data with the following line:

```
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1)
```

Here, you are setting the input_dim to 1 because you are considering each of the 21 variables as a separate 1D sequence with only one channel. This means that the CNN will look for patterns within each variable independently. If you had multiple channels or features for each variable, you could set the input_dim to a higher value.

The difference between the data shapes for LSTM and 1D CNN is that LSTM works with sequences (timesteps), while 1D CNN works with 1D spatial data (steps). The input_dim parameter in the 1D CNN is used to represent the number of channels or input features at each data point in the 1D spatial dimension.

Comment: So my CNN data reshape is correct? That is, X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1)

Answer (score 0):

The input shape for `Conv1D` should be the same as the `LSTM` data shape, just because both model sequences and so both require 3D input tensors of shape `[batch, steps, num_features]`. In you case you have `steps=3` and `num_features=2`, so the input shape for the `Conv1D` layer should be `(3,2)`.

This means that you can train the 1D CNN model with the data you have prepared for the LSTM model, i.e. `X_lstm`. There is no need to reshape you dataset `X`, just generate sequences as you already do with `generate_train_data()`.

If you want to not loose some input data due to sequence arrangement, you can pad them with zeros.

Another thing you want to consider with the 1D-CNN is that the kernel size will shrink the output of the convolution, so you may want to consider using padding as follows:

```py
cnn_model = Sequential()
# NOTE: padding=same, and input_shape taken from LSTM's data
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(16, 2, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=X_lstm.shape[1:]))
cnn_model.add(Flatten())
cnn_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
cnn_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```